# mySql syntax error behavior?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, syntax-error, tomcat6

i am executing this query :

INSERT INTO sent_emails (mailBody,azRatesFilesSendingId,fileName,tarrif_id,destination,cc,bcc,email_content,attached_file) VALUES ( 'Dear Sir,

Please find attached TELTAC WORLDWIDE Rate notification.
**As per account manager approval, increace effective today.**
 Please confirm your receipt to ra@teltacworldwide.com  Regards,
==================================**Rates Department****Teltac World Wide Inc.**Ibisa Bldg, 3rd Floor, Racreet, VerdunP.O.Box: 43 BrTel:  +9632 Ext: 114F338Email: ratom===================================

' , '33435','Teltac-Rate Sheet-ATel 2013-Apr-19','276','ratcation.com','ratrldwide.com','','View','Open')

it's giving me a syntax error when someone is trying to execute it:

error in DBHandler---executeUpdateQuery-->com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MsoNormal" style="margin: 0in 0in 0pt;">Dear Sir,

but when i execute it in the MySql server the statement executes successfully and returns one row was effected!
So i can see that it's not a syntax error but i cant figure out whats the problem!

Comment: Can you please post you Java code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with `String` concatenation and query building. Without the *actual code* this is just a guess, but it is an educated one.

This is a very common issue when inserting arbitrary `String`s into a database using `String` concetentation. For example

```
final String query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE value = '" + value + "'";
```

The above query looks good, it does what it's supposed to do. But what if `value` is something unexpected?

```
final String value = "damn, it's got an apostrophe";
```

Now suddenly you have a broken query. Even worse, what if we have

```
final String value = "something'; DROP DATABASE myDatabase --";
```

Then we have a real problem.

You should use a `PreparedStatement` to execute the query otherwise you can run into all sorts of strange issues, generally called SQL Injection.

Here is an example using your query and the `SET` syntax, which works better for clarity in `PreparedStatement`s.

```
final String query = "INSERT INTO sent_emails SET"
        + "mailBody = ?,"
        + "azRatesFilesSendingId = ?,"
        + "fileName = ?,"
        + "tarrif_id = ?,"
        + "destination = ?,"
        + "cc = ?,"
        + "bcc = ?,"
        + "email_content = ?,"
        + "attached_file = ?";
final PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStatement.setString(1, mailBody);
preparedStatement.setInt(2, azRatesFilesSendingId);
//and the rest of the parameters.
```

Comment: i agree with you on the above but when i execute this query directly to mySql in the MySql query builder and everything goes ok  but when it's executed in the production environment, it gives me this error but it inserts the query in the sent_emails table! it's a weird behavior!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an unescaped semi-colon somewhere and you aren't sql-injecting yourself? Is the _whole_ data inserted?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the formatting.

You have probably HTML Code with style information in your Mail Body, which also contains " ' ".

You should make sure to escape all single and double parenthesis before inserting the text into the DB.

Answer (score 0):

I used StringEscapeUtils from the apache .jar and it worked like a charm! I read that it's not safe since it could bring an issue of SQL injection, but since this application is only used internally than I think it's safe!